# ORA-20024: REST enablement for maintained schema disallowed

Tags: oracle, oracle-rest-data-services

I have set in ORDS without APEX when I try to enable the schema, I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
BEGIN

    ORDS.ENABLE_SCHEMA(p_enabled => TRUE,
                       p_schema => 'DEVUSER',
                       p_url_mapping_type => 'BASE_PATH',
                       p_url_mapping_pattern => 'devuser',
                       p_auto_rest_auth => FALSE);
    commit;
END;

Error report -
ORA-20024: REST enablement for maintained schema disallowed : DEVUSER
ORA-06512: на  "ORDS_METADATA.ORDS", line 183
ORA-06512: на  "ORDS_METADATA.ORDS_INTERNAL", line 281
ORA-06512: на  "ORDS_METADATA.ORDS_INTERNAL", line 688
ORA-06512: на  "ORDS_METADATA.ORDS_INTERNAL", line 640
ORA-06512: на  "ORDS_METADATA.ORDS_INTERNAL", line 779
ORA-06512: на  "ORDS_METADATA.ORDS", line 167
ORA-06512: на  line 3
```

Comment: are you using a Oracle in multitenant mode ??

Comment: No. I have Oraсle 19c, but I did not create a container base.

Comment: try the answer I post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most probable cause is because the schema has been created as an Oracle Maintained user. An Oracle Maintained user cannot be enabled for ORDS based REST services.

In order to correct this problem, you must delete and recreate the target schema.

1.To drop the user:

```
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;

drop user DEVUSER;

alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=false;
```

2.Recreate the user:

```
create user DEVUSER identified by <PASSWORD>;
grant create session to <SCHEMA>;
```

Perform any other grants needed for this user. If you have data to save, export it first ( using Datapump, for example ) and import it back again.

Comment: "Show con_name"  gives the following result: "CON_NAME Non Consolidated" and I have already recreated the user this way, but the error persists.

Comment: Run this `select oracle_maintained from dba_users where username = 'DEVUSER' ;` . If it is Y, then follow the steps of recreate the user

Comment: Roberto Hernandez,  thank you!! It worked when I followed all the steps again !!

Comment: can you accept the answer, please ? it is the best way to say thank you

Comment: @AndreyGorelov , you have an icon below the arrows up and down in your question to mark the answer as accepted. That way other people will know that the solution works.

Comment: I don't have 15 reputation to cast a vote. ((